# Make PhD citations say "dissertation" rather than thesis

Tags: bibtex, citing

At my school, PhD works are generally referred to as dissertations rather than theses.

My bibtex file has this entry:

```
@phdthesis{Alsolami2012Auth,
    title    = {An examination of keystroke dynamics for continuous user authentication},
    school   = {Queensland University of Technology},
    author   = {Alsolami, Eesa},
    year     = {2012}, %other attributes omitted
}
```

And it gets rendered as:

```
[2] Eesa Alsolami. An examination of keystroke dynamics for continuous user authentication.
PhD thesis, Queensland University of Technology, 2012.
```

Is there any way to make it say "PhD dissertation" rather than "PhD thesis"?

On another note, why is this the default in LaTeX? Would it be unusual or poor form to change it?

Edit: I'm using the `plain` bibliography style. I could probably use `ieeetr` as well:

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{myBibFile1,myBibFile2}
```

Comment: This depends on your bibliography style, not your `.bib` file. So you need to show the LaTeX code you are using to produce the bibliography for us to help you.

Comment: @AlanMunn Thanks, see edit. Using `plain` style.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The text used in `plain.bst` is hard coded into the file itself, and so isn't customizable from within your document.

What you can do is make a copy of `plain.bst` and edit it, and then use the copy as your bibliography style.

On a TeX Live system, `plain.bst` is located in `/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/base/plain.bst`.  Make a copy of this file and call it `plain-diss.bst` (or some other name).  Save this in the same folder as your document, or put it in your local `texmf` folder in `texmf/bibtex/bst/`.

Edit the file and search for "thesis".  You will find the following function:

```
FUNCTION {phdthesis}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  new.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  new.block
  "PhD thesis" format.thesis.type output.nonnull
  school "school" output.check
  address output
  format.date "year" output.check
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}
```

Change  `"PhD thesis"` to `"PhD dissertation"` and then save the file.

In your document, use `\bibliographystyle{plain-diss}` instead of `{plain}`.

The same general solution will also work for the `ieeetr.bst`.

### A biblatex solution

Another way to do this would be to use `biblatex`, which provides easy customization of these sorts of things.  Here's a schematic document that shows how to do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\addbibresource{<your-bib-fil>.bib}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{american}{phdthesis = {PhD dissertation}}
\begin{document}
\cite{<cite-key>}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly. I had to search my system (Cygwin) for the file with `find / -name plain.bst`. My `plain.bst` was at `/usr/share/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/base/plain.bst`.

Comment: Somebody at my school also pointed out that my PhD titles were italicized while my master's titles were not. Comparing the entries, I changed `format.btitle "title" output.check` to `format.title "title" output.check` to make them not italic.

Answer (score 21):

For a quick fix, you can use the `type` field, although it makes the file non portable.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@phdthesis{Alsolami2012Auth,
    title    = {An examination of keystroke dynamics for continuous user authentication},
    school   = {Queensland University of Technology},
    author   = {Alsolami, Eesa},
    year     = {2012},
    type     = {{PhD} dissertation},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\cite{Alsolami2012Auth}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this seems perfect, but could you pls elaborate on the "non portable" part?

Comment: @davyjones If you use the bib file for other purposes, you probably need to remove the `type` field.

Comment: that's nice. I thought the generated pdf file would be somehow self-contradictorily non-portable. Thanks~