# BibLaTeX - How to move "PhD thesis" elsewhere in bibliography entry?

Tags: biblatex, thesis

## Current behavior (undesired)

There are several thesis types available in BibLaTeX, such as `mastersthesis`/`mathesis` and `phdthesis`.  This question applies to any of them equally, but I will focus on `phdthesis` here.

For `phdthesis` entries, I get something like the following (after a few adjustments to periods and parentheses):

> Chomsky, Avram Noam. 1955. *Transformational Analysis*. PhD thesis. University of Pennsylvania.

## Desired

Now, while it's possible to modify *PhD thesis* and get *PhD dissertation*, described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175106/make-phd-citations-say-dissertation-rather-than-thesis), I would actually like to move it completely after the name of the institution.  Basically, this:

> Chomsky, Avram Noam. 1955. *Transformational Analysis*. University of Pennsylvania PhD thesis.

or, preferably:

> Chomsky, Avram Noam. 1955. *Transformational Analysis*. University of Pennsylvania dissertation.

Which is described in the Linguistic Society of America's [Unified Style Sheet](http://www.linguisticsociety.org/resource/unified-style-sheet).

The problem that I run into is that I cannot figure out how to reference the "PhD thesis" element.  According to bibtex's `btxbst.doc`, this element is hardcoded into `FUNCTION {phdthesis}`.

I would be ok with hacking it together by clearing the `PhD thesis` element and adding this to the institution element, but because it appears to be hardcoded at that very location I have no idea how to do it or if it is even possible.  If redefining various elements is not possible, is there some way to redefine `FUNCTION {phdthesis}` locally within the current .tex file (rather than editing the bibtex file)?

What is the best way to accomplish this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[%
    backend=biber,%
    citestyle=authoryear-comp,%
    bibstyle=authoryear,%
    natbib=true,%
    dashed=false,%
    ibidtracker=false,%
    isbn=false,%
    url=false,%
    eprint=false,%
    hyperref=false,%
    uniquename=false,%
    uniquelist=false,%
    block=none,%
    maxnames=3,%
    giveninits=false,%
]{biblatex}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

%clear some stuff
\AtEveryBibitem{%
    \clearfield{note}%
    \clearfield{pagetotal}%
    \clearlist{language}%
}

%Make all thesis/dissertation titles italic
\DeclareFieldFormat[thesis]{title}{\mkbibitalic{#1}}%

% DON'T put parentheses around year
\renewbibmacro*{date+extrayear}{%
  \iffieldundef{\thefield{datelabelsource}year}
    {}
    {\setunit{\addperiod\space}%
       \iffieldsequal{year}{\thefield{datelabelsource}year}
         {\printdateextralabel}%
         {\printfield{labelyear}%
          \printfield{extrayear}}}}%}%

\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@phdthesis{chomsky:1955,
    title = {Transformational Analysis},
    language = {English},
    school = {University of Pennsylvania},
    author = {Chomsky, Avram Noam},
    year = {1955},
    type = {phdthesis},
},
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{american}{phdthesis = {PhD dissertation}}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you show us an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) of your actual document, so we can see which bibliography package and style you use. In your question you mention `biblatex` and your question is tagged as such, but then you talk about `btxdoc` and BibTeX functions. A solution will very heavily depend on the used package and style.

Comment: You see, I mentioned `btxdoc` because I am searching around for where this _PhD thesis_ text is coming from and that was the only place that I could find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to move the field we need to modify the bibdriver for `thesis`. We can save ourselves copying and changing it by using the [`xpatch`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xpatch) package.

We simply remove the type earlier in the driver and insert our own macro which prints the thesis type after the institution.

```
% this macro is based on institution+location+date from standard.bbx
\newbibmacro*{institution+thesistype+location+date}{%
  \printlist{location}%
  \iflistundef{institution}
    {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}
    {\setunit*{\addcolon\space}}%
  \printlist{institution}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \printfield{type}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibdriver{thesis}
  {\printfield{type}%
   \newunit
   \usebibmacro{institution+location+date}}
  {\usebibmacro{institution+thesistype+location+date}}
  {}{}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[%
    backend=biber,%
    style=authoryear-comp,%
    natbib=true,%
    dashed=false,%
    ibidtracker=false,%
    isbn=false,%
    url=false,%
    eprint=false,%
    hyperref=false,%
    uniquename=false,%
    uniquelist=false,%
    block=none,%
    maxnames=3,%
    giveninits=false,%
]{biblatex}

%clear some stuff
\AtEveryBibitem{%
    \clearfield{note}%
    \clearfield{pagetotal}%
    \clearlist{language}%
}

%Make all thesis/dissertation titles italic
\DeclareFieldFormat[thesis]{title}{\mkbibitalic{#1}}%

% DON'T put parentheses around year
\renewbibmacro*{date+extrayear}{%
  \iffieldundef{\thefield{datelabelsource}year}
    {}
    {\setunit{\addperiod\space}%
       \iffieldsequal{year}{\thefield{datelabelsource}year}
         {\printdateextralabel}%
         {\printfield{labelyear}%
          \printfield{extrayear}}}}%}%

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@phdthesis{chomsky:1955,
    title = {Transformational Analysis},
    language = {English},
    school = {University of Pennsylvania},
    author = {Chomsky, Avram Noam},
    year = {1955},
    type = {phdthesis},
},
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{phdthesis = {dissertation}}

\newbibmacro*{institution+thesistype+location+date}{%
  \printlist{location}%
  \iflistundef{institution}
    {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}
    {\setunit*{\addcolon\space}}%
  \printlist{institution}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \printfield{type}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibdriver{thesis}
  {\printfield{type}%
   \newunit
   \usebibmacro{institution+location+date}}
  {\usebibmacro{institution+thesistype+location+date}}
  {}{}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

gives

> Chomsky, Avram Noam. 1955. Transformational Analysis. University of Pennsylvania dissertation.

Where we used `\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{phdthesis = {dissertation}}` to get "dissertation" instead of "PhD thesis".

Comment: This works, thank you!  I am a bit newer to biblatex and still in the learning curve.